# How to run classifications on video frames in Inception, without starting a new tensorflow session for every frame?

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I am using [this repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/label_image.py) to run a classifier on images with Inception. However, instead of running on images, I want it to loop over a video and run a detection on every frame. I adjusted the `read_tensor_from_image_file()` function so that it can process a frame instead of an image file, so that is great. However, what happens now is that for each frame, a new tensorflow session is started because of this bit:

```
 with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    start = time.time()
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                      {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
    end=time.time()
  results = np.squeeze(results)
```

(t is defined as `t = read_tensor_from_image_file()`)

My question is: how can I alter this code so that I can run a classification on a frame, without initiating a new tf.Session for every frame. Instead, I want to start one tf.Session at the start of the video, and close it at the end of the video.

Comment: Move the with tft.Session part to an appropriate scope, and pass the sess object around where it is needed

Comment: Ok, it worked indeed. I moved with tf.Session up, so it became: ```graph = load graph(), with tf.Session: for frame in video, t = sess.run()```.

Comment: Great. Will you make an answer to your post and approve it? Then others will find the solution easily as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    graph = load_graph(model_file)
    with tf.Session (graph=graph) as sess:    # initiate tensorflow session
        for t in frame_list:                  # framelist is a list with all frames
            results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
```